# Delegate NS resource record of IPv4 subnet

Tags: domain-name-system, subnet, reverse-dns

Is it possible for a reverse zone to name another DNS server in the NS record? I want to delegate DNS for all addresses within a subnet to a site using that subnet. Our office leases a subnet which is routed by our ISP. We want to overcome the limitations on when and what records we may modify - currently, only PTR is allowed and we have to submit an e-mail.

---

Example: The ISP's name servers resolve 200.0.16.0/27 which is routed by the ISP to a customer's site. The customer runs a local DNS server. Is it possible to set a RR for each member of 200.0.16.0/27 besides ISP's name server in order to allow the customer to administer the network more autonomously? ISPs do offer DNS RR for IP addresses and a network name in Whois, so why not delegate the zone?

Comment: Is it too abstract? My intention was **not** to limit the question to business needs in my region, especially in the case of ISPs being a very _regional_ matter. Considering resources may be withheld from our ISP, the issue is whether or not there is any technical reason behind it.

Comment: It might possibly be too abstract but I've reopened it anyway. It would make a stronger question to describe the specific problem you are trying to solve in the context of your business needs. See also [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/126632) and [What information should I include or obfuscate in my posts?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way the reverse lookups were designed, they must be delegated on octet boundaries.  The original design assumed that networks would be delegated on class boundaries, which correspond to octet boundaries.  Likewise IPv6 reverse delegation is by nibble.  This is why common delegations are /64, /56, and /48.

[RFC2316 Classless IN-ADDR.ARPA delegation](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2317.txt) discusses the issue.  Subnets which don't fall on these boundaries must be delegated buy delegating individual address (or block for more general delegations).

Comment: If I did unsterstand RFC2317 correctly, the owner of a zone refers by CNAME to the fully qualified subdomain within in-addr.arpa. With regards the example given, a zone file _ORIGIN 2.0.192.in-addr.arpa._ contains a record _129 CNAME 129.128/26.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa._ which is recorded in another zone file -  _$ORIGIN 128/26.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa._. Disregarding 5.3, it seems to me that there is a solution: We negotiate a CNAME record and manage our own zone file.

Comment: @user2964971 That is how I read it.